Snowflake - Timestamp stale of a stream
Is there a way to obtain the stale_after of a stream as a select to use it as a condition?
I know you can use a SHOWS STREAMS and it gives the parameter but i want to use the timestamp for another logic, is there a way to do this?

Just use RESULT_SCAN after running SHOW STREAMS

@NickW after executing the SHOW STREAMS with the one i want, i create a temporary table as create or replace temporary table db.schema.demo1 as
SELECT * from TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())); But after this when i tried to execute: select stale_after from db.schema.demo1; i got the error: Error: invalid identifier 'STALE_AFTER'

So what have you done to investigate and resolve this issue?

You Could use the RESULT_SCAN function after running "show streams".
Example:
show streams;
select "stale_after" from TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));

Please note that the SHOW command generates lowercase column names,use delimited identifier notation (double quotes) around the column names in the query to ensure that the column names in the query match the column names in the output that was scanned.
Please review the below documentation for more information:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-streams
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan#examples-using-describe-and-show-commands
